# Embedding WMV file in Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: embed, dreamweaver

My video does not play when I upload it to my site, it only plays it in the dreamweaver preview screen. Video also does not play in the properties tag inspector, keeps saying unable to find the plugin that handles this media type. Also, how do I get the video to display the first frame, just shows a black screen. Am I missing something in the code? I have included my code and website.

http://www.raphaelsphotopage.com/Locomotive%20Gallery.html

```
>         <object classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsm
> p2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112" type="application/x-oleobject"
> width="300" height="300"
>     standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..." id="MediaPlayer">
>     <param name="FileName" value="3039.wmv">
>     <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
>     <param name="autostart" value="false">
>     <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
>     pluginspage=" http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/"
>     src="3039.wmv"
>     width="300" height="300" showcontrols="1" showstatusbar="0" showdisplay="0" autostart="0"></embed>
>     </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

type="application/x-oleobject" is not supported by all browsers. So what you have will only work in some browsers (notably IE and Safari). It fails however in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. Check out this page with a workaround.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1625235.aspx/1

Comment: When I copied your code earlier into a new html file, and replaced the source with the source of your WMV (full http url), it worked in Safari, but not Chrome, Firefox, or Opera. I do not have IE to test.

Comment: Did you write the full url like this: <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage=" http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" src="http://www.raphaelsphotopage.com/3039.wmv"
width="300" height="300" showcontrols="1" showstatusbar="0" showdisplay="0" autostart="0"></embed>